# Python, remove specific columns from file

Tags: python, text, text-processing

I have a file in the following format ;

```
string1     string2         ........    stringN

value1,1    value1,2    ........    value1,N
   .            .       ........        .
   .            .       ........        .
   .            .       ........        .
valueM,1    valueM,2    ........    valueM,N
```

M is on the scale of 10000
N is on the scale of 100

Which I need to;

- remove empty lines
- remove first two columns
- keep 7th,14th,21th ... columns and delete the rest

from this file respectively.

it gets very tricky with numpy since there are strings (titles of each column) in this data as well. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You've given us a specification of your data, and what you want done, specifically, but no actual question or problem. Where is the code you tried? What was wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a custom ASCII-table-like format with fixed-with columns:

```
*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
*    Row   * Instance * test_string * test_string * test_string * test_string * test_string * test_string * test_string * string__722 * string__722 * string__722 * string__722 * string__722 * string__722 * string__722 * string__720 * string__720 * string__720 * string__720 * string__720 * string__720 * string__720 * HCAL_SlowDa * HCAL_SlowDa * HCAL_SlowDa * HCAL_SlowDa * HCAL_SlowDa * HCAL_SlowDa * HCAL_SlowDa * string__718 * string__718 * string__718 * string__718 * string__718 * string__718 * string__718 * string__719 * string__719 * string__719 * string__719 * string__719 * string__719 * string__719 * string__723 * string__723 * string__723 * string__723 * string__723 * string__723 * string__723 * string__721 * string__721 * string__721 * string__721 * string__721 * string__721 * string__721 * another_str * another_str * another_str * another_str * another_str * another_str * another_str * another_str * another_str *
*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
*        0 *        0 *           0 *    50331648 * test_string *           2 *           1 *          13 * 5.76460e+18 *           0 *    50331648 * string__722 *           2 *           1 *         606 * 5.83666e+18 *           0 *    50331648 * string__720 *           2 *           1 *         575 * 5.83666e+18 *           0 *    50331648 * HCAL_SlowDa *           2 *           1 *          36 * 5.76460e+18 *           0 *    50331648 * string__718 *           2 *           1 *         529 * 5.83666e+18 *           0 *    50331648 * string__719 *           2 *           1 *         529 * 5.83666e+18 *           0 *    50331648 * string__723 *           2 *           1 *         529 * 5.83666e+18 *           0 *    50331648 * string__721 *           2 *           1 *         529 * 5.83666e+18 *           0 *    50331648 *      212135 *       15080 *           1 *           1 *        3340 *        1057 * 1.399999976 *
*        0 *        1 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          13 *           0 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         606 *       53440 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         575 *       53440 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          36 *           0 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 *       53440 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 *       53440 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 *       53440 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 *       53440 *           0 *    50331648 *      212135 *             *           1 *           1 *        3340 *        1057 * 1.399999976 *
*        0 *        2 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          13 *  4294970636 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         606 * 1.09780e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         575 * 1.09780e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          36 * 2.70217e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.09780e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.09780e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.09780e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.09780e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *      212135 *             *           1 *           1 *        3340 *        1057 * 1.399999976 *
*        0 *        3 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          13 *   352321545 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         606 * 2.30610e+18 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         575 * 2.30610e+18 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          36 * 7.30102e+18 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *      212135 *             *           1 *           1 *        3340 *        1057 * 1.399999976 *
*        0 *        4 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          13 *           0 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         606 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         575 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *          36 * 2.82590e+16 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *             *           2 *           1 *         529 * 1.15294e+19 *           0 *    50331648 *      212135 *             *           1 *           1 *        3340 *        1057 * 1.399999976 *
```

If we assume that none of the actual data fields contain asterisks themselves, the easiest way to read each row is to use a regular expression to split out the lines.

To output, I'd still use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), because that would make future processing that much easier:

```
import csv
import re
from itertools import islice

row_split = re.compile('\s*\*\s*')

with open(someinputfile, 'rb') as infile, open(outputfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')

    next(islice(infile, 3, 3), None) # skip the first 3 lines in the input file

    for line in infile:
        row = row_split.split(line)[1:-1]
        if not row: continue
        writer.writerow(row[8::7])
```

This skips empty rows, and writes only every 7th column (counting from number nine) and skips the rest.

The first row thus is:

```
['5.76460e+18', '5.83666e+18', '5.83666e+18', '5.76460e+18', '5.83666e+18', '5.83666e+18', '5.83666e+18', '5.83666e+18', '3340']
```

Comment: `valid = (row[::7] for row in reader if row); writer.writerows(valid)` would be my style, but anyway...

Comment: @JonClements: I deliberately kept a full `for` loop here to keep it simpler for the OP to grok all this.

Comment: works with the standart csv file but what if the delimiter is not constant throughout the file ?

Comment: @y33t: And how would you go about detecting that the delimiter changes?

Comment: delimiter changes 7 blank spaces to 10 depending on the column title, thus it should be achievable I think ? I added * as delimiter for now since I am doing this for experimental purposes.

On the other hand as I stated I don't need first 2 columns, and after that I need each 7th column so (column index 0 is first column) ; 8th, 15th, 22th, 29th, 36th and so on. I constructed the following loop ;     
prefix=0
    for row in reader:
        if not row: continue
        writer.writerow(row[::8+prefix])
        prefix=prefix+7


but not providing expected outputs ?

Comment: I uploaded my data with delimiters embedded to here ;

http://www.2shared.com/document/pdRuhJvX/test_data.html

Comment: You have a fixed-with format using `*` as separator, to build a faux ASCII table. Oh dear.

Comment: @y33t: Must the output use the same layout? I'd say that that would be rather.. tricky.

Comment: Did you mean fixed-width ? I am trying to learn and experiment but couldn't find any pointers online thus needed help from experienced users /:

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it looks tricky. I need the numerical values of 8th,15th,22th... columns. Output format is fine as long as I load it with numpy.loadtxt and plot it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought first column is column[0] thus shouldn't 8th column of first raw be ; 5.83666e+18 ?

Another thing is I got ;

row = row_split.split(line)[1:-1]
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @y33t: Note that the `csv` *reader* is gone, I am reading the file directly now. if `line` is a csv row, then that won't work. to use the *9th* column, simply add 1. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters 'reader' is not define here but is being called from ; next(islice(reader, 3, 3), None) thus getting 'reader' not defined.

if I add ;   reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='*')
I get ;     row = row_split.split(line)[1:-1]
TypeError: expected string or buffer

still. What am I missing ? (:

Comment: Sorry about that, corrected. A case of old names needing replacing.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the string values (like string__722) and save to a numoy array ? Didn't want to ask a new question thus asking here.

Comment: @y33t: Sure it is, just apply the same splitting to the second line; replace the `next(islice(inputfile, 3, 3), None)` line with the following three: `next(inputfile) # skip a line of asterisks`, `headers = row_split.split(next(inputfile))[9:-1:7]`, `next(inputfile) # skip another line of asterisks`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters results 'headers' is a list and I try to convert it to an array to reach individual components with array(header) but I index out of bounds for array(headers)[1] and the rest ?

Comment: @y33t: Sorry, I'm a numpy n00b; You have a list of strings there, not sure how that jives with numpy arrays.

Comment: @MartijnPieters array() is the way to go here, I mistyped it obviously, not it functions as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is removing empty lines:

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: not re.match(r'^\s*$', x), original)
```

To remove a specific column (I assume your data is stored in a text file):

```
f = open("textfile.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("newfile.txt","w")
```

Write your lines back, except the lines you want to delete:

```
list = [0, 1, 6, 13, 20] # remove first,second as well as 7th, 14th and 21th line
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
  if i not in list:
    f.write(line)
```

At the end, close the file again.

```
f.close()
```

Comment: Please read the OP again, your post has nothing to do with it.